# Error de Decodificacion Cesar

Tags: c++, codeblocks

tengo un problema con la siguiente lógica, estoy realizando el código para descifrar la Decodificacion Cesar, ya que la codificación ya la realice, pero no logro hacer que las 3 primeras letras del abecedario funcionen, me saltan caracteres distintos a letras o letras al azar.
Si me pueden indicar donde podría estar mi error, o porque no capta las 3 últimas lo agradecería[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 char p[100];
 char alf[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
 cout<<"ingrese palabra a decodificar"<<endl;
 gets(p);
 int j;
 for(int i=0;i<strlen(p);i++){
  j=0;
  while(j<52){
   if(p[i]==alf[j] && (j<23||(j>=26 &&j<49))){
    p[i]=alf[j-3];
    j=52;
      }
   if(p[i]==alf[j] && (j>=23 && j<26)){
    if(p[i]=='x'){
        p[i]='a';
    }
    if(p[i]=='y'){
        p[i]='b';
    }
    if(p[i]=='z'){
        p[i]='c';
    }
    j=52;
   } else
   {
       if(p[i]==alf[j] && (j==0 && j<2))
       {
        if(p[i]=='a'){
        p[i]='x';
        }
        if(p[i]=='b'){
        p[i]='y';
        }
        if(p[i]=='c'){
        p[i]='z';
        }
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sabía lo que era la Decodificación Cesar así que [lo he buscado en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_C%C3%A9sar):

> Es un tipo de cifrado por sustitución en el que una letra en el texto original es reemplazada por otra letra que se encuentra un número fijo de posiciones más adelante en el alfabeto. Por ejemplo, con un desplazamiento de 3, la A sería sustituida por la D (situada 3 lugares a la derecha de la A), la B sería reemplazada por la E, etc.

Parece una tarea ideal para [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::string Cesar(const std::string frase, int desplazamiento)
{
    std::string result;
    std::transform(frase.begin(), frase.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
        [&desplazamiento](auto &c) { return c + desplazamiento; });
    return result;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJha8IwEP1sfsXRgbRMZSD7Up1fxvYn5hhnktbDNJEkZUzxt3dJWzcVh/tSyLu79969K99uxyXnTXNHmqtaSJiTcd5KrBbsF0NVGkt@fQaGNtLlgjHnRZ53L3iWDm3KjXYeTvHCopMjIO1BSLdVuMOKpPYmY3s2OO200tXKz3rQW9SuMLZKW4bJSpak02zUEU6kFvHRtq6Qbz5IO2m9tGlHE2pvw3PB9xRrb2DIM9gHMV9bDRzuL2zN4JAFD3396OnAWNygwujh0njr6Oibm9rDfA7Ja0QBgRtBBXG0OSTHplJ6RVqm3QTpfqsgzAatSR7ThKc@1T7DaVu/phJuFNJBlcMySSLeTrQNy2Spkz/MHa0J/BnshG8NVqhibFfm@98gfkfwmN1k@gfLeHpO05/mIVylaV4UFFLRDqracpIKSwNr0qIOy1UU0kcrSCkDX7ChT2Lf)</kbd>.

La codificación y descodificación funcionaría con la misma función: si codificas con `3` descodificas con `-3`.

Si nos queremos ceñir a la César de manera estricta (es decir: que sea sólo alfabética y no una operación de desplazamiento) podemos usar aritmética modular para buscar el carácter de substitución:

> *Carácter* = (*Posición* + *Desplazamiento* + *Caracteres de la clave*) Módulo *Caracteres de la clave*

```
std::string Cesar(const std::string frase, int desplazamiento)
{
    std::string clave{"abcdefzhiklmnopqrstvxABCDEFZHIKLMNOPQRSTVX"};
    auto busca_posicion = [&clave](const std::string::value_type &c)
    {
        auto posicion = clave.find(c);
        return posicion == std::string::npos ? 0 : posicion;
    };

    const std::string result;
    std::transform(frase.begin(), frase.end(), std::back_inserter(result),
        [&](const std::string::value_type &c)
        {
            if (auto posicion = busca_posicion(c))
                return clave[((posicion + desplazamiento) + clave.size()) % clave.size()];
            return c;
        });

    return result;
}
```

He usado los 21 caracteres del [alfabeto Romano](https://lengua.laguia2000.com/general/el-alfabeto-romano) (pero en versión mayúsculas/minúsculas). Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVPvb9MwEP1c/xWnICpbdNWkiS9ZNwSDCcT4jRCinSrXcTJrjh1sp4JW/duL7aRZU0Dbl0h3fu/d3bsLq6qjgrHt9pFQTNYZh4nQ1hlOy3N0l6Oy0Ea4m17Sw4QqzhGyLkvTJoILbqnBTCvrYD@fG2r5CIRykHFbSbqipeDKaYLWaLCPZJIu@TqhC5bxfHUjbmWpdPXTWLf89fzFxctXlz9ev3l79e79h4@fPn/5@u17sjlFA1o7DYvaMjqvtBVMaAVnMB1Gteu/G0rTJZU1n7vfFYchI2jg22hU9viRPc6FyjAjvsrAcFcbtQc564sq/wLP4BjSDuNpvsH@jIbbWrrTNukMVTbXpsTRpfGCF0JhMmpMG3Nf3QcRuqDsdi6U5cZxgxsZMvKNTYcPGjJOORA54MNR@975cQO6GzgaMcW4Izw5XKPPNG5ZseKYEHjci6@De51aCDYkuNJmdoZsEAonUtJgwOFlRDt2pjFdO5hMILkMWaDAdCZywahJIdmBCu6kUBw3DKFaS2PlaAAL5@qnb862PdIT0u3roIr/CfxqqExhliQhHxkRMEtmKvlPc7vWMtoRm8L3EUsqg8//4Lf/WfiO4Cm5V@kBKkcnfZl2Ncd@K9vt3VZgDd0LbNAf)</kbd>.

Te advierto que el código no tiene en cuenta UTF8 multicarácter, pero tampoco lo hacían los Romanos ni mi código original.

Comment: Prueba a codificar `ZZAAzzaa` :) Si salen caracteres no imprimibles entonces rompes la codificación

Comment: [As you wish](https://tio.run/##jVLRasIwFH02X3HpQFpWZSB7qU6QwT7COcY1jV1YmpQkfVH89i5J001FcS@BnHvOuSf3hjbNpKK06x64pKItGSy4MlYzrJfkD0NRKc3t1xnoaFxWS0KMLYuiv8ErM6hTqqSxcIrvNBqWA5cWSmYagXusOZNWZeRARqdMzUwr7DyCVqM0O6XrNDhMt6ziMs3y3nDKZOkvgbpF@v3JpWHaMp32Nq72Pj5v@JFiaxWMaQYH18y2WgKFx4tYczhmLkOsD5mOhPgX1OgzXAYPiYbcVLUWFgtI3jwKCFSVfMcp6gKSgVQxK7hkaa/gMr7KNSajEJL6acJLnGqc4SzUr3VxO3LTQVHAJkk8HhSBsEk2MrkRbohW4q@wb3xPWKPwY7uij9/Anzk8Z3ed/uEymZ3bxNU8ua103Xq9Wu33iOQH "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online"). Ningún problema.

Comment: `]]` no forma parte de la codificación cesar. Es un cifrado meramente alfabético

Comment: Piensa que en la época de los romanos no se estilaba mucho eso de usar corchetes, almohadillas, arrobas, comillas y demás

Comment: Los romanos tampoco usaban ordenadores para codificar, pero podemos pasar el código a losas de piedra a ver qué tal funciona O_o

Comment: Me refiero a que todos esos caracteres no forma parte del diccionario utilizado por el algoritmo. Los romanos no usaban ASCII, luego no tiene sentido basar la codificación en el orden en el que aparecen los caracteres en dicha tabla

Comment: Podemos ir un paso más allá y reemplazar todos los números por numerales romanos, y eliminar las letras que no conformen las 21 letras originales del alfabeto romano… y tatuar el resultado en el cuero cabelludo de un esclavo, resucitar a Julio y mostrarle el resultado, eso sí sería codificación César. Ô____ô

Comment: El cifrado, hasta donde se, se limitaba al texto. Los números no se codificaban luego puedes ahorrarte esa conversión. En cualquier caso, la codificación tampoco afecta a los espacios mientras que tu versión sí... **estás haciendo un cifrado César a la PaperBirdMaster**

Comment: De hecho la propia wiki te da la codificación ... es en módulo 27

Answer (score 2):

Te estás complicando demasiado. Para empezar, aparte del error que comentas, tu codificación no funciona. `xyz` no se debe cifrar a `abc` sino a `uvw`, ya que le deberías restar 3 a cualquier palabra... **la suma es para la decodificación**.

Si te dedicas a sumar unos caracteres y a restar otros va a ser complicado que luego consigas recuperar el texto original.

Fíjate que si tratas `alf` como un buffer circular verás que es todo mucho más sencillo, ya que te dará igual si codificas o decodificas:

```
std::string alf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
std::cout<<"ingrese palabra a decodificar\n";
std::string frase;
std::getline(std::cin, frase);
std::cout << frase << '\n';

for( char c : frase )
{
  bool encoded = false;
  for( int i=0; i<alf.length(); i++ )
  {
    if( alf[i] == c )
    {
      int newIndex = i - 3;
      if( newIndex < 0 ) newIndex += alf.length();

      std::cout << alf[newIndex];
      encoded = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if( !encoded )
    std::cout << c;
}
```

También puedes evitarte el chequeo de índices negativos usando el operador módulo:

```
int newIndex = (i + alf.length() - 3) % alf.length();
```